# SlideToggle on only the clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m using this to show a sublist:

```
    function slidecontent() {
        $('ul.joinus_subtext').slideToggle();
    }
```

and I have this markup:

```
    <ul class="joinus">
        <li onclick="slidecontent();">Benefactor
            <ul class="joinus_subtext">
                 <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia mi a turpis tempor blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci 
                                luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nullam sit amet ante sed tellus rutrum porta ut non ipsum.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li onclick="slidecontent();">Protector
            <ul class="joinus_subtext">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia mi a turpis tempor blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci 
                                luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nullam sit amet ante sed tellus rutrum porta ut non ipsum.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The problem I have is that when I click on one **LI it toggles all, not just this one, how can I toggle one, then if I open the other close the one before?**

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$('ul.joinus_subtext').on('click', function(){
    $(this).slideToggle();
});
```

And remove the `onclick="slidecontent();"` in the HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry slight edit;

```
<li onclick="slidecontent(this);">
```

Try;

```
function slidecontent(that) {
    $(that).find('ul.joinus_subtext:first').slideToggle();
}
```